MacBook A1342 boot issues after Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS desktop installation
I have a old (and very beat up) late 2009/ mid 2010 MacBook 13 inch, A1342, recently installed with desktop version of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. The iso image is written onto a SanDisk thumbdrive using rufus-4.6, all iso is written without changing any of the default setting. The installation is done without connecting to the wifi, interactive installation, default selection of apps, install third-party software for graphics and wifi, erase disk and install ubuntu. After prompting me to restart upon completion of the install, the system refuses to boot up.
Boot screen during restart:

Only after pressing Command+R was I only able to boot up. This issue persist despite having update all the software and drivers, thus I am currently now very confused.
What did I do wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

My apologies for the vagueness. The flavor of the ubuntu installed is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I used rufus 4.60 to write the iso image into a SanDisk Ultra USB3.0 32GB tumbdrive as my bootdrive.

Rufus allows reformatting of ISO too, so options matter; a reformatted incorrectly ISO may not boot if options used during Rufus write aren't correct for your hardware...  For best results don't use options in ISO write; just clone or write the ISO using options found within the ISO correctly (this is called I believe dd-mode with rufus, but sorry I don't use that app).   This is a Question & Answer site & not a forum, so please add additional details to your question; comments will be removed once addressed in question itself, answers being to question details & not readers comments
